# How compare variable according the dropdown list?

Tags: r, excel, vba, bert-toolkit

I have a df and I import it :

```vb
Sub ()
Dim Path As Variant
r = "df = read.csv('df')"
Application.Run "BERT.Exec", r
End Sub
```

And I have some function like in Bert environment!

```r
c_1 <- function (var1,var2) {
  require(tidyverse)
  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  var2 <- enquo(var2)
  df %>% 
    mutate(RG = ifelse(!!var1 > !!var2, 1, 0)) %>%
    select(RG,ID)
}


c_2 <- function (var1,var2) {
  require(tidyverse)
  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  var2 <- enquo(var2)
  df %>% 
    mutate(RG = ifelse(!!var1 = !!var2, 1, 0)) %>%
    select(RG,ID)
}
```

For each fuction I have

```vb
ID RG
1  1
2  0
3  1
```

Then I have a sheet excel "Parametre" like that :

[image: that]

And I want to compare variable according the dropdown list. 
I want to to this for many rows

I tried this macro but it's no ok (i have nothing on my sheet test). I want for each i copy my value in a column of the sheet "test"

I want to get results for each i ! and copy in column.

```vb
Sub test()
Dim v As Variant
Dim var1 As Variant
Dim var2 As Variant
Sheets.Add.Name = "test"
With Worksheets("Parametre")
        For i = 19 To 10
            For j = 2 To 10 Step 2
            If (Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i))) Then
                If (Range("B" & i) = ">") Then
                        var1 = .Cells(i, 1).Value
                        var2 = .Cells(i, 3).Value
                    v = Application.Run("BERT.Call", "c_1", var1, var2)
                    ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Select.Value = v
                End If
                If (Range("B" & i) = "=") Then
                        var1 = .Cells(i, 1).Value
                        var2 = .Cells(i, 3).Value
                    v = Application.Run("BERT.Call", "compare_inf", var1, var2)
                    ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Select.Value = v
                End If

            End If
           Next j
        Next i
End With
End Sub
```

At the end I want on a sheet "test"

```
   A  B C 
1  Id Rg_1 Rg_2
2  1  1    1
3  2  0    1
```

Comment: If BERT is freely available please provide download links so that we can play with it.

Comment: https://bert-toolkit.com/downloading ! thank you !

Comment: `For i = 19 to 10` - this shouldn't work - the loop would just terminate immediately. You need to add `Step -1` to the end of that (`For i = 19 to 10 Step -1`).

Comment: it's Ok I replace 10 by 29 but it's not ok to..

Comment: You have described what you've got, but not what the problem is... what's the question? Are you getting any errors? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon please?!